# Red Black Tree delete malfunction in C

Tags: c, red-black-tree

I have almost completed a red black tree but my delete is malfunctioning. It may delete a node it may not. After i delete the root and press the print option my screen is spammed of nodes that i already have in the tree. in a test tree of `2,1,7,5,8,11,14,15,4` if i delete `root=7` and press in-order print i get `2,4,5,8,1,2,4,5,8,1,.....` and so on until the program crashes. If i delete 2 the program instantly crashes. Node 11 deletes fine as do all leaves like 1-4-15. I've tried to find the problem with debugging but everything seems to work fine. The code is based on Cormen's introduction to algorithms. Thanks!

```
void RB_delete(struct node* z,struct node* y) //delete z y=z on call
{
    struct node *x;
    enum type originalcolor;         //x  moves into y's original position
    originalcolor=y->color;     // Keep track of original color

        if (z->LC==nill)        //case 1: (z has no LC)
        {
            x=z->RC;
            RB_transplant(z,z->RC); 
        else if (z->RC==nill)           //case 2: z has LC but no RC
        {
            x=z->LC;
            RB_transplant(z,z->LC);
        }
        else            // two cases: z has both Children
        {
            y=tree_minimum(z->RC);      //find  successor
            originalcolor=y->color;     //save color of successor
            x=y->RC;
                if (y->P==z)    //successor has no LC cause its nill
                    x->P=y;
                else
                {
                    RB_transplant(y,y->RC);
                    y->RC=z->RC;
                    y->RC->P=y;
                }
            RB_transplant(z,y);
            y->LC=z->LC;
            y->LC->P=y;
            y->color=z->color;
        }
        if (originalcolor == black)
            RB_delete_fix(x);
        free(z);
}

void io_print(struct node *aux,struct node *auxnill)
{
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if(aux != auxnill)
    {
        io_print(aux->LC,auxnill);
        if (aux->color==red)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 12);
            printf("%d,\n",aux->key);fflush(stdout);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);
        }
        if (aux->color==black)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 9);
            printf("%d,\n",aux->key);fflush(stdout);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 15);
        }
            io_print(aux->RC,auxnill);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean that when you debug it does no crash?

Comment: `nill` should read `nil`. It stands for latin [nil](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihil) ("nothing") and not in list.

Comment: when i delete 7 it deletes fine in the debugging but when i use print i get 
`root:8
in order RB tree:{1,2,4,5,8,1,2,4,5,8,1,2,4,5,8,......` to infinity...

Comment: nill is a sentinel. its a struct that replaces null. i think that some pointers are wrong but i cant find them...

Comment: I understood what you use nill for. But such a sentinel is commonly referred to as "nil", just saying. ;)

Comment: I won't be able to help w/o my own algorithm book, bur have some suggestions/ideas. 1, add your delete_fix function, and remove the print (you say it prints fine before deleting. 2, rb trees need left and right rotates. Are you sure you got both? Doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @gnometorule i have all the functions that i need i just didnt post them here. Btw i think i have found (almost) the problem but cant fix it. When it changes the pointers in transplant in case where the successor y's right child x is pointing to nill (the sentinel), it breaks the connections of the tree. it acts to it like a normal node and tries to place it in the tree BUT its nill(no values) and so it creates a broken link. node's child pointing to itself etc. :/ and here is the mess now cause i cant figure how to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there was a single misplace of pointer in transplant... And i couldnt find it cause i didnt paid much attention. i had:

```
void RB_transplant(struct node *aux,struct node *auxchild)  //replace the subtree rooted at node aux with the subtree rooted at aux-LC or aux->RC
{
    if (aux->P==nill)                           //if aux=root child becomes root
        root=auxchild;
    else if (aux==aux->P->LC)               //if child is a LC
        aux->P->LC=auxchild;                
    else aux->P->RC=auxchild;                   //if child is RC //connect grandparent's->RC with child
        auxchild->P=aux->P;                         //connect child to point to parent
}
```

and the problem was in line 5 where aux was=>auxhild... Problem sovled :)